# Android - UIAutomator how to keep momentum while dragging?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I have the following command in my UI test:

```
device.drag(437, 589, 377, 0, 3);
```

The x and y values came from a use case with the user. But I realised that, when the user was testing the application and it scrolled down, the application kept the momentum of the movement. Is there any way that I can do so in using the UIAutomator?